# How to check key of an object exists in a more sophisticated way

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object to check if each keys exists or not.

```
 { _id: 5e907e4047dd2f290ea4d23b,
  username: 'gg',
  email: 'gg',
  isSensei: false,
  location: 3,
  location2: 0,
  age: 7,
  country: 'AI',
  introduce: 'Nice to meet you' }

if (obj.hasOwnProperty(username) && obj.hasOwnProperty(email) && ... ) {
   // do something
}
```

If part looks very long and ugly.
Is it possible to check wether each fields exists or not in a single line of code ?

Comment: obj.username.hasOwnProperty(username) <-- that is invalid syntax to start

Comment: obj.key will return undefined if not exist, so you can use it in conditions like this: if (obj.key) or if (!!obj.key)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you can get with [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) all the keys from your object. Then with [`.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) combination you can identify if all the keys are reflected in your object what you are looking for, for example from the `fieldsToCheck` array what I created for better representation.

Try as the following:

```js
const obj =  { _id: '5e907e4047dd2f290ea4d23b', username: 'gg', email: 'gg', isSensei: false, location: 3, location2: 0, age: 7, country: 'AI', introduce: 'Nice to meet you' };

const fieldsToCheck = ['email', 'username', 'location'];
const keys = Object.keys(obj);

const hasAll = fieldsToCheck.every(e => keys.includes(e));

console.log(hasAll);
```

See the essential part from the documentation for [`.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

> The `every()` method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value.

So at the end you could use further like the following:

```
if (hasAll) {
   // your code
}
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `Object.keys()` and `Array.prototype.every()`.

```js
const data = {
  _id: '5e907e4047dd2f290ea4d23b',
  username: 'gg',
  email: 'gg',
  isSensei: false,
  location: 3,
  location2: 0,
  age: 7,
  country: 'AI',
  introduce: 'Nice to meet you'
};


const keys = Object.keys(data);
const isExistsEveryKeys = keys.every(key => data[key] !== undefined); // This will check every keys existance, If all the keys exists then it returns true, and returns false otherwise.

console.log(isExistsEveryKeys);
```